# Django: Using a variable as the URL namespace?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a submenu for a sports site. Each sport would need its own submenu. The problem I'm having is I need the namespace itself to be dynamic in someway.

SportListView returns the sport so I can then filter the news articles by the sport.

Views:

```
class SportListView(ListView):
    template_name="sports/sport-home.html"
    context_object_name='sport_list'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SportListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['sport_menu'] = get_object_or_404(Sport, 
sport_slug=self.kwargs['sport_slug'])
    return context
```

Template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-nav">
    <a href="{% url 'sports:sport-home' sport_menu.sport_slug %}">
    {{sport_menu.name}}</a>
    <a href="{% url sport_menu.sport_slug 'monthly' %}">Monthly View</a>
</nav>
```

The first link in the submenu works fine. As you can see it effectively acts as a home button for each sport.

The second link does not on the other hand. In the error message it returns the slug of the sport but I can't get that to act as the namespace.

I do have an app and its URLs.py file configured correctly for the current sport as well by the way. So I know that isnt the problem.

edit:

Current error message I'm getting withi this configuration is:

> Reverse for 'cricket' not found. 'cricket' is not a valid view
>   function or pattern name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template filter:

```
<a href="{% url sport_menu.sport_slug|add:':monthly' %}">Monthly View</a>
```